# While loop is duplicating instead of incrementing results

Tags: javascript, json

I am successfully showing all the results of my comparison between two object value, but when I add...

```
while (l++ < 12) {
    Do Something
}
```

to the code below in the l for loop.

Basically I am comparing the values from the navigation subcategories to the subcategories in the articles and displaying the results via the...

```
if ( thisArticleContainerSlug === thisArticleSlug.subcategoryslug ) {
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the while loop duplicates my results instead of incrementing them.

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < data.nav1.length; i++) {
navigationLevel = data.nav1[i];
    var navigationSubLevel = navigationLevel.subcategories;
    <section>
        if ( navigationLevel.hasOwnProperty("subcategories") ) {
            <ul>
                for (j = 0; j < navigationSubLevel.length; j++) {
                    <li>Do something..</li>
                }
            </ul>
            for (k = 0; k < navigationSubLevel.length; k++) {
                var thisArticleContainerSlug = navigationSubLevel[k].subcategoryslug;
                <div>
                    for (l = 0; l < data.articles.length; l++) {
                        var thisArticleSlug = data.articles[l];
                        while (l++ < 12) { <----- This is where I am adding the while loop
                            if ( thisArticleContainerSlug === thisArticleSlug.subcategoryslug ) {
                                <article>
                                    Do Something
                                </article>
                            }
                        } <------ This where it closes
                    }
                </div>
            }
        }
    </section>
}
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Please show the code where you have added the while loop into the code so we don't have to guess.

Comment: And remove all the irrelevant, confusing `<% %>`

Comment: This does not appear to be just JavaScript. Could you please indicate what HTML templating language is being used?

Comment: It seems like you'd be iterating the same `data.articles` structure each time you enter the `L` loop.  I would expect the same results from that loop each time it runs, ie, duplicates.

Comment: Please also indicate _where_ the `while (l++ < 12) {` block is proposed to be added to the larger piece of code.

Comment: Just updated the question as requested.

Comment: Mark A. Fitzgerald the engine is EJS

Comment: James, basically I am comparing the values from the navigation subcategories to the subcategories in the articles and displaying the results via thisArticleContainerSlug === thisArticleSlug.subcategoryslug. But when I try to restrict the results with the while loop it duplicates them rather than incrementing them

Comment: @Rob as requested I have removed <% %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue myself, but for brevity sake and anyone else having this issue I have added the solution below...

Thank you @James for providing the seed!

What was wrong...
As @James pointed out I was iterating the same data.articles structure each time by using the while loop.

The solution was to create a variable equal to 0 outside of the for loop and inside the if statement create a second if statement with the limit of iterations and increment the variable inside that if statement.

```
<% var ifStatementIterationLimit = 0; %>
for (l = 0; l < data.articles.length; l++) {
    var thisArticleSlug = data.articles[l];
    if ( thisArticleContainerSlug === thisArticleSlug.subcategoryslug ) {
        <% if (ifStatementIterationLimit < 12) { %>
            <article>
                Do Something
            </article>
            <% ifStatementIterationLimit ++; %>
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you @Felix Brunet for attempting a solution.

I hope this helps someone else in the future =]

Answer (score 0):

If I take only the most important part of the code : (I re-added the EJS mark because they are useful, but note that you can make multi line Javascript code with EJS)

```
<% for (l = 0; l < data.articles.length; l++) {
    var thisArticleSlug = data.articles[l];
    while (l++ < 12) { <----- This is where I am adding the while loop
         if ( thisArticleContainerSlug === thisArticleSlug.subcategoryslug ) {%>
              <article>
                    <%Do Something%>
              </article>
         <%}
    } <------ This where it closes
}%>
```

As I understand now (with the help of the comment), you want to filter the articles to keep only the one that `thisArticleContainerSlug === thisArticleSlug.subcategoryslug` and you want to limit the number of result to 12.

you can not do this with the for loop. as you do it now, you limit the number of article checked in "data.articles" to the first 12.

to do want you want, you need first to create a list of all the article you want and after, limiting is size to 12.

you could do it with another variable like so :

```
<% for (let l = 0, goodArticle = 0; l < data.articles.length && goodArticle < 12; l++) {
     var thisArticleSlug = data.articles[l];
     if ( thisArticleContainerSlug === thisArticleSlug.subcategoryslug ) {
          goodArticle++;%>
          <article>
                <%Do Something%>
          </article>
     <%}
}%>
```

but I find it much better with an ES5/ES6 style (all code in EJS work with node, so there is no possible old browser incompatibility)

```
<% data.articles
    .filter(thisArticleSlug => thisArticleContainerSlug === thisArticleSlug.subcategoryslug )
    .slice(0, 12).forEach(thisArticleSlug  => {%>
          <article>
                <%Do Something%>
          </article>
<%})%>
```

note that this may be not exactly what you wanted to do, as it was not stated explicitly in the question what was the end goal.

Comment: Felix Brunet thank you for your reply, when I add && l < 12 it now only shows the first result it finds, the same applies to slice(0, 12). Basically I am comparing the values from the navigation subcategories to the subcategories in the articles and displaying the results via the if statement thisArticleContainerSlug === thisArticleSlug.subcategoryslug. But when I try to restrict the results with the while loop it duplicates them rather than incrementing them .

Comment: Felix Brunet I have also tried moving the while loop inside the if statement and the result remains the same.

Comment: Felix Brunet thanks for the multiline tip it will save a lot of typing

Comment: I edited my answer without seeing you had already found what you wanted yourself.